# Rollup - Preserve modules + css

Tags: rollup

Can't find any resources online, but i'm trying to optimize our in-house component library, which i'm trying to make more tree shaker friendly.

How with rollup can i leave .css files in the output along with maintain their import in the file.

I.E

```
Foo.js  (inside import "./foo.css")
Foo.css
```

Output.

```
Foo.js  (inside import "./foo.css" remains) created into module
Foo.css
```

This seems as straight forward as possible and iv'e found similar threads asking for this but zero responses. https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss/issues/204

Allowing this will basically mean when people who consume my project will only get critical css automatically.

I.E   Import { Foo } from "xyz/foo" will automatically import the accompanying css file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution with Rollup for what you're looking for. However, if you're open to using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) there's a plugin that would make this possible called [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin). It creates CSS files per JS file and would achieve the structure you're wanting.